# create a python module which is understood by jupyter notebook from inside a conda environment

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have installed anaconda and using conda I created an environment. All packages except zenlog which was installed using pip inside the env, were installed using conda.

I have two modules (.py files) written the following way both of which have the error I describe below.

The modules are stored in the /Documents/python/project directory along with the environment file I used to create and activate this environment.

All libraries or packages are visible using `conda list` and import correctly. It's just my simple module that fails when I try to create an object of the `logtextfile` class.

when I create an object from my logging module (which I call mylog.py) I get the error: `

> NameError: name 'logtextfile' is not defined

This error occurs when I create a jupyter notebook in the same directory as my mylog.py module and import it as follows:

```
import mylog  # A simple module to log a message to a text file.
```

But when I copy the class and functions of the mylog module into a cell of the testing.ipynb jupyter notebook and create an object of the class it works without a problem.

---

**What do I have to do differently when creating an object of the logging class when it's in a module (a separate .py file) as compared to a jupyter notebook cell?**

---

**The file structure of my project folder is:**

Folder: /Documents/python/project directory

File testing.ipynb

File mylog.py

..

**My module is:**

```
import datetime
import os

class logtextfile(object):   
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return "{} ".format(self.__class__.__name__)

    def write(self,**kwargs):
        """Writes a log message to a user specified file which indicates the action takes and if it was successful"""
        self.file = kwargs.get('file',"log.txt")
        self.loglevel = kwargs.get('loglevel',"critical")
        self.logmessage = kwargs.get('logmessage',"error")
        self.success = kwargs.get('success',False)
        self.class_name = kwargs.get('class',str("{}".format(self.__class__.__name__)))
        self.output = ", ".join([str(datetime.datetime.now().replace(second=0,microsecond=0)),self.class_name,str(self.logmessage),str(self.success),str("\n")])

        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self,key,value)

        f = open(str(self.file),"a")
        f.write(self.output)
        f.close()

    def now(self, filename, openas, data):
        """Creates a log file with todays date and time"""
        fmt='%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S_{fname}'
        fn = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(fmt).format(fname=filename)
        f = open(str(fn),openas)
        f.write(data + "\n")
        f.close()
```

**Here is a copy of my conda environment** 
If anyone wants to try creating an object of the logging class inside a jupyter notebook cell and by importing it from my mylog.py file.

Requirements:

- Anaconda installed
- Create environment from file

```html
<pre>
  <code>
name: stocks_library
channels:
- anaconda-fusion
- defaults
dependencies:
- appnope=0.1.0=py35_0
- beautifulsoup4=4.5.3=py35_0
- blaze=0.10.1=py35_0
- bleach=1.5.0=py35_0
- bokeh=0.12.5=py35_0
- chest=0.2.3=py35_0
- click=6.7=py35_0
- cloudpickle=0.2.2=py35_0
- cytoolz=0.8.2=py35_0
- dask=0.13.0=py35_0
- datashape=0.5.4=py35_0
- decorator=4.0.11=py35_0
- entrypoints=0.2.2=py35_1
- flask=0.12.1=py35_0
- flask-cors=3.0.2=py35_0
- h5py=2.6.0=np110py35_0
- hdf5=1.8.15.1=2
- heapdict=1.0.0=py35_1
- html5lib=0.999=py35_0
- icu=54.1=0
- ipykernel=4.6.1=py35_0
- ipython=6.0.0=py35_0
- ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py35_0
- ipywidgets=6.0.0=py35_0
- itsdangerous=0.24=py35_0
- jinja2=2.9.6=py35_0
- jsonschema=2.6.0=py35_0
- jupyter=1.0.0=py35_3
- jupyter_client=5.0.1=py35_0
- jupyter_console=5.1.0=py35_0
- jupyter_core=4.3.0=py35_0
- libiconv=1.14=0
- libpq=9.5.4=0
- libxml2=2.9.4=0
- libxslt=1.1.29=0
- llvmlite=0.11.0=py35_0
- locket=0.2.0=py35_1
- lxml=3.7.3=py35_0
- markupsafe=0.23=py35_2
- mistune=0.7.4=py35_0
- mkl=11.1=np110py35_p1
- mkl-rt=11.1=p0
- mkl-service=1.1.0=py35_p0
- multipledispatch=0.4.9=py35_0
- mysql-connector-python=2.0.4=py35_0
- nbconvert=5.1.1=py35_0
- nbformat=4.3.0=py35_0
- networkx=1.11=py35_0
- notebook=5.0.0=py35_0
- numba=0.26.0=np110py35_0
- numexpr=2.4.6=np110py35_0
- numpy=1.10.2=py35_p0
- odo=0.5.0=py35_1
- openssl=1.0.2k=1
- pandas=0.18.1=np110py35_0
- pandas-datareader=0.2.1=py35_0
- pandasql=0.7.3=py35_0
- pandocfilters=1.4.1=py35_0
- partd=0.3.7=py35_0
- path.py=10.3.1=py35_0
- pexpect=4.2.1=py35_0
- pickleshare=0.7.4=py35_0
- pip=9.0.1=py35_1
- postgresql=9.5.4=0
- prompt_toolkit=1.0.14=py35_0
- psutil=5.2.2=py35_0
- psycopg2=2.7.1=py35_0
- ptyprocess=0.5.1=py35_0
- pygments=2.2.0=py35_0
- pymysql=0.7.9=py35_0
- pyqt=5.6.0=py35_2
- pytables=3.2.2=np110py35_0
- python=3.5.3=1
- python-dateutil=2.6.0=py35_0
- pytz=2017.2=py35_0
- pyyaml=3.12=py35_0
- pyzmq=16.0.2=py35_0
- qt=5.6.2=0
- qtconsole=4.3.0=py35_0
- readline=6.2=2
- requests=2.13.0=py35_0
- requests-file=1.4.1=py35_0
- scikit-learn=0.17=np110py35_p1
- scipy=0.16.1=np110py35_p0
- setuptools=27.2.0=py35_0
- simplegeneric=0.8.1=py35_1
- sip=4.18=py35_0
- six=1.10.0=py35_0
- sqlalchemy=1.1.9=py35_0
- sqlite=3.13.0=0
- terminado=0.6=py35_0
- testpath=0.3=py35_0
- tk=8.5.18=0
- toolz=0.8.2=py35_0
- tornado=4.4.2=py35_0
- traitlets=4.3.2=py35_0
- wcwidth=0.1.7=py35_0
- werkzeug=0.12.1=py35_0
- wheel=0.29.0=py35_0
- widgetsnbextension=2.0.0=py35_0
- xz=5.2.2=1
- yaml=0.1.6=0
- zlib=1.2.8=3
- pip:
  - ipython-genutils==0.2.0
  - jupyter-client==5.0.1
  - jupyter-console==5.1.0
  - jupyter-core==4.3.0
  - prompt-toolkit==1.0.14
  - tables==3.2.2
prefix: /Users/joshua/miniconda3/envs/stocks_library
  </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: `logging` is the name of a module in the standard library.  Have you tried using a different name?  If you have, and the error persists, please post the complete traceback and the exact code you are running (your example does not contain the word `company`, so it is unclear what might cause the error).

Comment: @cco I've updated my question to hopefully help you help me identify where my code is wrong. i've tried a different name to logging from the standard library I called it mylog.py

Comment: @cco thanks - your comment prompted me to have another look at the code and I realised I need to reference the object then call the function. For example the module is called mylog.py and the function is called logtextfile(). To get the name object I need to call: module.function_name() or mylog.logtextfile()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here I referenced the module incorrectly while trying to create the object.

> Where as I tried logger = logtextfile("myfile")

I should have written:

```
import mylog
logger = mylog.logtextfile("myfile")
logger.write(logmessage="mymessage",success=True)
print("log complete")
```